# Winter is coming, and so is Winter bash 2017!

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Winter bash is a yearly holiday event on StackExchange during which users can earn "hats" for specific activities and types of participation. The goal is to promote activity during the holiday season. This year, [winter bash will start on 13 December](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303371/340816) and will end on 3 January 2018.

If you are new to winter bash you can read a [short description of Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270508/340816). The hat your earn will disappear again [after winter bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159171/340816). Participation is entirely optional.

In other words, [**hats are coming soon!**](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/)